# pass event from UserControl to parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know how to register event that happened inside of user control  in my form.
Form has 3 FloatLayoutPanels
Each FloatLayoutPanel has list of UserControls.
Each UserControl has ComboBox
I would like to be able to move UserControls between FloatLayoutPanels on ComboBox onvaluechanged event.
In order to do that I would need to register that event from UserControl ComboBox happened in the main form

Here is my UserControl constructor:

```
public event EventHandler SelectedStatusValueChanged;


public ucNarudzba()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.cmbPromjenaStanja.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbPromjenaStanja_SelectedValueChanged);
    }
```

this is my combobox SelectedValueChanged event

```
 private void cmbPromjenaStanja_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedStatusValueChanged != null)
            SelectedStatusValueChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

Then in my form I should access event something like this
(not sure if this is correct)

```
private void ucNarudzba_SelectedStatusValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do what I want
        
    }
```

and if it is correct I dont know how to write code in form's designer.cs file that would call this event!

So I am asking for feedback if this is ok method to get event data from user control to form, and help with calling event from form's designer.cs file.

Any help is appreciated!!!!

Comment: Suggested googling and reading: **[What is the preferred way to bubble events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349195/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-bubble-events)** Several hundred thousand other posts here as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did u add this line to your form
`UserControl1.SelectedStatusValueChanged += new EventHandler(ucNarudzba_SelectedStatusValueChanged);`